# How to test a TRIAC with just a digital multimeter and no external circuit

Tags: multimeter, triac, test

I need to fix an electric kettle and would like to test the health of the TRIAC BTA20. How would you test this component health with a digital multimeter - without any extra components and ideally without removing it from the circuit?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Jf2z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Testing first and third quadrant operation of a triac.*

*If* your multimeter has a high enough diode test voltage and current then the circuit of Figure 1 might work. SW1 and 2 can be replaced by a piece of wire or paperclip.

I've never tried this so I'd be interested to know if it works.

Comment: If it conducts either way without closing the switch it is likely to be broken.

Comment: most multimeters have too low a diode test voltage to test blue LEDs, so, this would really be lucky! But anyways, excellent idea!

Comment: You could in theory add a battery and use the multimeter in current-measurment mode, if its diode test voltage is too low. At least, I think. I don't work with triacs often.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really test it with a multimeter alone.

A triac is not a device fully described by any two of its ports, so, a multimeter alone can't do.